# RabbitMQ Is it possible to duplicate some messages within RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a requirement to deliver the same message to two consumers using different routing keys. One option is to modify the code in the message creator but I hoped there may be a way to do this within RabbitMQ.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can setup your exchange to be `fanout` exchange. By doing this, all queues that are bound to the exchange will receive the messages. Checkout this image so that you can understand more:

[image: fanout exchange]

You can checkout this link for fanout tutorial: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

Comment: Thank you. Is this possible with different exchanges? We have existing code in live using one exchange and we are introducing a refactored service that will replace it but we want to live test. It will have a different exchange and queue .

Comment: I think to live test. You shouldn't have new exchange but just setup new queue that bound to current exchange. That will work.

Comment: The image is taken from this great RabbitMQ tutorial: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html